# MySQL, how to split string and use where clause at the same time?

Tags: mysql

**Table**

[image: Screenshot of Table Furnitures]

I have snippets of data entries in `Furnitures` table as shown in the image above. My goal is to identify if one of the `ItemPrice` field (comma delimited) has above 30. How do I do that?

In this case, at `id == 1`, we have `23,42,12`, which means it found that 42 is greater than 30, thus the query will display the whole row.

**Query**

`SELECT *
 FROM Furnitures 
 Where ItemPrice >= 30`
//from this point, I have no idea what should I put here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should avoid storing CSV data directly into your SQL tables.  But, sometimes we are stuck with the bad design decisions made by other people.  One way to proceed here would be to use `REGEXP` to detect a number in the CSV list of item prices which is greater than 30:

```
SELECT *
FROM Furnitures
WHERE
    CONCAT(',', ItemPrice, ',')
        REGEXP ',(3[1-9]|[4-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]+),';
```

[image]

In the demo below, I have slightly modified your data by making the second row have no items with a price greater than 30.

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, but I got an error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'"...im not sure why...

Comment: @learnprogramming You probably copied my answer wrongly.  It works in the demo, and that is as much as I can help you.

Comment: This works like a charm! I got minor mistakes just now. Thank you very much